# Problema al migrar desde laravel a mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, ubuntu, migration

Me dieron unos archivos de *Laravel* que son las tablas de la base de datos de un compañero, me explico debía de copiar esos archivos a la carpeta **`database/migrations/`** y luego debía de ejecutar el lo siguiente:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 



could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = seguros-app-laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')



at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕ 

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Cabe recalcar que tengo un servidor *MySQL* local el cual estoy usando para hacer esta migración.

Comment: Te dice que no tienes el driver de mysql, si lo tienes haz: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: verifica que  `php -m` muestre en el listado la extensión pdo-mysql o la mysqli (no me acuerdo cuál se usa en Laravel). Además, configura el DB_HOST usando la IP, no el alias 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

Ve a tu archivo .env y reemplaza estos valores por los de tu server.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```